Skipping acquire of configured file - doesn't support architecture 'i386' Ubuntu 24.04
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 LTS and faced some warnings when running sudo apt-get update. The log message in the end is:
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Previously, I was using Ubuntu 22.04 and saw similar warnings. Here's my current Ubuntu version information using the lsb_release -a command:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble

I am not very experienced with Linux and Ubuntu, only familiar with basic commands and configurations. I tried to change the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.sources file to:
Types: deb [arch=amd64]
URIs: https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
Suites: stable
Components: main
Signed-By:
 -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
XXXXXX
 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

I changed only Types value from deb to deb [arch=amd64] but this raised an error:
E: Type '[arch=amd64]' is not known on stanza 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.sources
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Can someone please help me on how to resolve these warnings?

For sources.list files in DEB822 format, you would add a separate Architectures: amd64 line instead of qualifying the Type entry - see for example this answer

Thank you, this has solved my issue.

For reference, this has been answered back in 2021 here
